# ODP.NET Connection exception

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

First I would like to say that I am not familiar at all with Oracle databases, so my words might be poorly chosen and my understanding of some concept might be wrong...
Anyway, I am trying to connect to an Oracle 11g database using ODP.NET  and every time it gives me this exception :

```
System.TypeInitializationException occurred
HResult=-2146233036
Message=The type initializer for 'OracleInternal.Network.AddressResolution' threw an exception.
Source=Kiwi.ServiceBase
TypeName=OracleInternal.Network.AddressResolution
StackTrace:
    at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.CreateNewPR(Int32 reqCount, Boolean bForPoolPopulation, ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, String instanceName)

    at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)

    at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)

    at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword)

    at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()

    at Kiwi.DataAccess.OracleDataService.get_DbConnection() in c:\Projects\Kiwi-Beta7-0\Kiwiweb\src\Common\ApplicationServices\DataService\OracleDataService.cs:line 28

    InnerException: System.TypeInitializationException
        HResult=-2146233036
        Message=The type initializer for 'OracleInternal.Network.LDAP' threw an exception.
        Source=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
        TypeName=OracleInternal.Network.LDAP
        StackTrace:
            at OracleInternal.Network.LDAP..ctor()
            at OracleInternal.Network.AddressResolution..cctor()
        InnerException: System.NullReferenceException
            HResult=-2147467261
            Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
            Source=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
            StackTrace:
                at OracleInternal.Network.LDAP._LDAP(Hashtable dsMap)
                at OracleInternal.Network.LDAP..cctor()
            InnerException:
```

Called from :

```
private System.Data.IDbConnection _dbConnection;
public override IDbConnection DbConnection
{
    get
    {
        if (_dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            _dbConnection.Open();        // Crash from HERE
        return _dbConnection;
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Additional info : am also trying to connect without the tnsname.ora file. This is a windows service running on the same server that the database is located on.

I tried the following connection strings, the first one works in debug (and is the one constructed by the application) :

```
Data Source=demosyr20140329:1521/demosyr;User ID=SEI;password=manager;Pooling = False;

Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)       (HOST=DEMOSYR20140329)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=DEMOSYR)));User Id=system;Password=manager;

Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DEMOSYR20140329)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=DEMOSYR)));

Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DEMOSYR20140329)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=DEMOSYR)));  User Id=system;Password=manager;

User Id=system;Password=manager;Data Source=oracle

Data Source=system/manager@//DEMOSYR20140329:1521/DEMOSYR;
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Can you show where you instantiate _dbConnection?  It may be as something as simple as a bad connection string.  Oracle's error messages are not always intuitive.  Connecting without tnsnames should be no problem (and may save you headaches in the long run anyway).  Your Oracle client works fine outside of .NET?

Comment: Showing the code constructing the string would clutter my post, but I added the connections strings I tried. I think my Oracle client is fine, since I can query my database using SQLDeveloper. Let me know if you have better tests to check if my Oracle is well installed, since I am really new to Oracle stuff.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This guy helped me solve my problem
https://pravsdatums.wordpress.com/2013/12/16/ocac-12c-and-visual-studio-developer-tools/#comment-1

The solution was to remove LDAP from NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH in the sql.ora file. This file is located on your client home directory (this path can be found on one of the key in the registry under HLM/SOFTWARE/ORACLE). So the content of the file went from

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (none)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (LDAP, TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

To

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (none)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (EZCONNECT, TNSNAMES)
```

And now it works ! I don't know why it was working on my development machine (maybe because Oracle is not installed on it).

Hope it can help somebody else !

Comment: +1. I had the same problem! My path was in : `"C:\oracle\instantclient_11_1\SQLNET.ORA"`

Comment: @wetwillie Is there any way to store this in the project rather than in the registry of the machine it is running on? I am trying to keep everything that is involved in Oracle within my project. I don't want to install anything on the machine my application is deployed to.

Comment: Looks like I can just add a `<settings>` block under the `<version>` block in the app.config and include all the settings from the sql.ora file there.

Comment: I finally got mine working by adding this to my app.config `<setting name="NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH"  value="(HOSTNAME)" />` instead of  `<setting name="NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH"  value="(LDAP, TNSNAMES, HOSTNAME)" />`

Comment: I too had to remove the LDAP.  I was still having the problem but after restarting IIS, it started working. These files appear to be cached, so make sure you restart IIS if you are still having issues.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the connection string is an issue.  Some suggestions:

1. Can you connect to the database using SqlPlus or SqlDeveloper
   locally?
2. If the answer to (1) is true, then I would try to modify
   _dbConnection.ConnectionString directly in the code until I got it right.  If you are using tnsnames.ora for sqlplus connections, I
   would take the code from there are put it in the connection string
   and verify the connection as a sanity check.  I know this is not your ultimate objective, but you must start somewhere.
3. If the answer to (1) is false, I would work on getting that connection right first before attempting a connection through ODP.Net.

Comment: I can run queries from sqlDeveloper so I think this part is fine. I tried modifying the connection string directly, but every changes tried throw the same exception, as if it didn't even try it. I could retry my strings and copy them here if you want, would it be useful ?

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea.  Add them to your question.  I suspect you will need to experiment a little until you get it right.

Answer (score 0):

As well as fixing sqlnet.ora as described above, also check your TNS_ADMIN environment variable points to the correct network\admin path for your Oracle client.  Once this is correct, reboot and all should be well!