# How to connect to oracle database with ODAC c#

Tags: c#, oracle, odac

I am using this code but getting an error of 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' at con.open() ? what am I doing wrong ?

I have already download and installed ODAC component  version 10 , 11 ,12 trying each one at the failure of the latest one  but still same error

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class OraTest
    {

        public OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
        public void Connect()
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =myip) (PORT = myport))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME = mydb)));User ID=myid;Password=mypass;";

            con.Open(); //error here

        }

        public void Close()
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Did you install an Oracle Client?

Answer (score 2):

Please go through this link

Getting Started with Oracle Data Provider for .NET (C# Version)

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/GettingStartedNETVersion/GettingStartedNETVersion.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you add a try/catch block in Connect(), you'll be able to catch the error.

For example:

> [When opening an oracle connection, connection object is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264420/when-opening-an-oracle-connection-connection-object-is-null)
>
> I added the try catch block, and it returned ORA12154 - TNS could not
>   be resolved. After some research, I added an SID to my tnsnames.ora
>   file in my ODP for .NET Oracle home path, and it worked

See also [Troubleshooting Oracle Net Services](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14212/troublestng.htm) for troubleshooting possible connection issues from Oracle clients (such as your C# program).

But your first step is absolutely to determine the Oracle-level error (for example, ORA-12543 (could not connect to server host) or TNS-12514 (could not find service name)

[MSDN: OracleException Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

```
public void ShowOracleException() 
{
   OracleConnection myConnection =
      new OracleConnection("Data Source=Oracle8i;Integrated Security=yes");

   try 
   {
      myConnection.Open();
   }
   catch (OracleException e) 
   {
     string errorMessage = "Code: " + e.Code + "\n" +
                           "Message: " + e.Message;

     System.Diagnostics.EventLog log = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
     log.Source = "My Application";
     log.WriteEntry(errorMessage);
     Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred. Please contact your system administrator.");
   }
}
```

It's significant that `con.ConnectionString = xyz` works, but the following `con.Open()" fails.  This means .Net is creating the C# object, but Oracle/TNS is failing when you try to use it.

ADDITIONAL SUGGESTIONS:

- Re-read

  [When opening an oracle connection, connection object is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264420/when-opening-an-oracle-connection-connection-object-is-null).

  Read *all* of the suggestions, including the one about "Data Source in your connection string".
- Focus on your connection string.  It couldn't hurt to specify the connection string in your OracleConnection() constructor, if possible.  Here's another link:

  [ODP.NET Connection exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508402/odp-net-connection-exception)
- It would be great if you can verify connectivity from your PC with some *other* Oracle client, besides your C#/.Net program.  To verify you're talking to the right TNS host and service, with the correct username/password.  For example, maybe you have SQLDeveloper or sqlplus.
- Finally, re-read the TNS troubleshooting link:

  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/trouble.htm#NETAG016

Comment: try catch is not working , the error is thrown in same way around debug mode highlights the line

Comment: Q: Did you look for any inner exceptions in the exception object you got in your try/catch?  ALSO: I updated my post with an MSDN example of catching an OracleException object.

Comment: inner exception has given me this 'System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()'

Comment: With your excpetion example , its same message caught

Comment: Worked , I had to remove the reference and add old version of reference ! , Thanks guys for your reply and effort

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me with the same error was to simply switch from the 'plain' Oracle DataAccess library, to the 'Managed' version.
This is an extemely easy change to make -

1. Add a Reference in your c# project to the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` library
2. Replace the existing `use` statements at the top of your Oracle client code with the following:

   ```
   using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
   using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types;
   ```
3. Include the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` file with your exe