# How to connect to oracle using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Tags: c#, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to connect to oracle data base using below code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;

using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string connectionString =
                "Data Source=a;User Id=id;Password=pwd;";

            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to Oracle Database {0}", con.ServerVersion);
            con.Dispose();

            Console.WriteLine("Press RETURN to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }
}
```

> Its throwing exception saying:
>
> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in
>   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
>
> Additional information: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently
>   know of service requested in connect descriptor.

Can any body correct me what was going wrong with the above code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275376/oracle-managed-odp-net-cant-find-tnsnames-ora

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456024/why-would-oracle-manageddataaccess-not-work-when-oracle-dataaccess-does

Answer (score 0):

the issues maybe is the connection string, if you haven't *TNS name* "a" registered
you can try this

```
string connectionString = 
"Data Source=localhost:1521/xe;User Id=USERDB;Password=pwd";
```

by default XE is name for oracleservice
where

> Data Source  -> localhost:1521/xe (ip:port/servicename)
>
> User Id  -> you Oracle user
>
> Password ->  you Oracle password